# Change formatting/structure of .bib file?

Tags: bibliographies, bibtex, bibliographystyle

I have custom .bst file which I must use. However, for the citations to work correctly, my .bib file entry for website for example needs to look like this:

```
@misc{web_page,
author = "LLC",
title = "{MS Windows NT Kernel Description [Online]}",
howpublished = "Available at: \url{http://web.archive.org}",
note = "[Accessed: 19. 4. 2013]" }
```

However, when using `Zotero` or any other tool to generate .bib file, website entry looks like this:

```
@misc{noauthor_smart_nodate,
title = {Smart contract languages},
url = {https://ethereum.org},
abstract = {An overview and comparison of the two main smart contract languages – Solidity and Vyper.},
language = {en},
urldate = {2018-01-01},
journal = {ethereum.org},
file = {Snapshot:C\:\\Users\\example\\Zotero\\storage\\test123\\languages.html:text/html},}
```

Now if I cite this using the .bst style it comes out wrong, so .bib entry needs to be in format of first code snippet. I have lots of sources, is there any way to convert the .bib to this format/structure ? I already have templates how each entry (website,book, etc...) should be structured, however it seems I can't change the way .bib file is generated with any tool?

How should I go about acomplishing this? Is there any tool that allows me to generate a .bib file according to the template input, or something that is able to convert my .bib file to the structure? I really don't want to be making the .bib file by hand. (Note: I changed some words in my template to English since they were in my language)

Comment: Welcome to TeX.se. This may be able to be done using `biber` in `tool` mode. But is there any reason you can't fix the `.bst` file instead? See [Prevent \`biber --tool\` from removing non-standard fields in .bib files](//tex.stackexchange.com/q/415028) for an example of how tool mode can be used.

Comment: You may want to look into using `biblatex`. It also has an IEEE style but it’s easier to modify things.

Comment: Since you said that you need to use a fixed `.bst` file I removed the `biblatex` tag: `biblatex` is not compatible with `.bst` styles and comes with its own sets of styles.

Comment: In theory Zotero has all the data available that it needs, but it is used to producing output that is more detailed than the format your `.bst` file needs. Maybe you can rustle up something with https://retorque.re/zotero-better-bibtex/. That plugin allows you to customise lots of things about the export. (Do make sure the output format is set to BibTeX and not `biblatex`. - If there is such an option.)

Comment: Okay if anyone is interesd, i actualy kind of managed to do it both ways actually, biblatex actualy provides input quite close to one im required to do and its in my language too (will see if they accept input with only few colons in different style), i also managed to create url to be in correct place with better bibtex addon, this way still requires to input accesed date into "note" field manualy though, but its better than nothing.  For some reason i cannot see my comments from before anymore like they were deleted by admin or something. anyway, thanks to both of you for suggestions!